# Closure properties of transitive classes when forcing with $\kappa^+$-cc forcing

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Let us consider $M\subseteq V$ a transitive class such that $M^\kappa\subseteq M$ for some cardinal $\kappa$. Now take $\mathbb{P}$ a $\kappa^+$-cc (or $\leq\kappa-$distrivutive) forcing notion in $V$. Then it is the case that, provided that $G\subset \mathbb{P}$ is $V$-generic, then $V[G]$ also thinks that $M[G]^\kappa\subseteq M[G]$. I would be interested in to know a detailed proof of both facts because I have founded them mentioned everywhere but, unfortunattely, without any kind of explanations.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let me give an incorrect argument:

Working in $V[G]$, suppose $X_\eta$ ($\eta\in\kappa$) is a $\kappa$-sequence of *sets* in $M[G]$. Then we get a $\kappa$-sequence of *names* $\nu_\eta$ in $M$ which correspond to those sets: $\nu_\eta[G]=X_\eta$. Since $M^\kappa\subseteq M$, we have $(\nu_\eta)_{\eta\in\kappa}\in M$. But from this and $G$, we can construct the sequence $(X_\eta)_{\eta\in \kappa}$ in $M[G]$. So $M[G]^\kappa\subseteq M[G]$.

Why is this wrong? Well, the sequence $X_\eta$ exists in $V[G]$, not $V$; so $V$ might not see the sequence of names $\nu_\eta$. If $V$ doesn't see it, then $M$ doesn't have it, and so we're stuck.

---

How do we get around this? I'll answer for the $\kappa^+$-c.c. case; hopefully it will be clear how to handle this for the distributive case.

Suppose the theorem fails. Then there is a name $\mu\in V$ for such a sequence of names $\nu_\eta\in M$ which give a sequence of sets in $M[G]^\kappa$ but not $M[G]$. Now, the key point is that *each $\nu_\eta$ is in $M$, and hence in $V$!* So what $\nu_\eta$ is, is forced by some single condition in $G$.

For each $\eta$, let $A_\eta$ be a maximal antichain of conditions which decide what $\nu_\eta$ is. By the chain condition on $\mathbb{P}$, $A_\eta$ has size $\le\kappa$; by the closure condition on $M$, this means $A_\eta\in M$, and by the closure condition *again* the sequence $\mathcal{A}=(A_\eta)_{\eta\in\kappa}$ is in $M$. But from $\mathcal{A}$ and $G$, we can construct the sequence of $X_\eta$s in $M[G]$: given $\eta$, look for a condition $p\in G$ which forces a value for $\nu_\eta$, and then evaluate that name.

Comment: That was my problem... I reached your same proof but I don't know where $\kappa^+-$cc-ness is expected to appear..

Comment: There is a subtle issue here: each of the names $\nu_\eta$ is in $M$, but the whole sequence only lives in $V[G]$. You need the extra assumptions on $\mathbb{P}$ to get the sequence itself (or a good enough approximation) in $V$.

Comment: Of course, Cummings' chapter from the Handbook. It's on page 804.

Comment: @Cesare I was totally wrong, see Miha's comment above. I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: Thank you @NoahSchweber !! But only one more thing: the name for the sequence $(X_\eta)_\eta$ would be $\bigcup_\eta \{\{op(\eta,\nu_\eta)\}\times A_\eta\}$?

Comment: @Cesare What is "op"?

Comment: It's the name for an ordered pair. I used that to build a name for the sequence $(X_\eta)_\eta$.

Comment: More precisely, the evaluation of $op(\eta,\nu_\eta)$ by $G$ is $op(\eta,\nu_\eta)_G=\langle \eta, X_\eta\rangle$. Since every $A_\nu$ meets $G$ then the evaluation of $\bigcup_\eta\{\{op(\eta,\nu_\eta)\}\times A_\eta\}$ is the function $\{\langle \eta,X_\eta\rangle:\;\eta\in \kappa\}$.